# npm global install of ganache-cli fails (because of sudo/permissions)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, ganache

I have npm version 6.5.0 and node v10.10.0.
There have been no previous issues with npm global installs.

```
sudo npm install --global ganache-cli

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-305900d8
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-305900d8': Permission denied
npm ERR!     
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-12T20_49_21_325Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to install npm packages. If I were you I would use a Node version manager which negates the permissions issue entirely. I could post an answer explaining how to do that if you fancy.

Comment: i tried it without sudo, but that was another permission issue. i always have used sudo in the past for global installation.  my /usr/local/lib/node_modules folder is owned by root.

Comment: Whether you have done it in the past is besides the point. You shouldn't install random code from the internet on your machine as root, especially when using a version manager means you don't have to. And leaving out sudo won't help much either if your permissions are borked to start with.

Comment: Makes sense. I deleted everything in /usr/local/bin/node_modules/ and /usr/local/lib/nodemodules/ and the npm cache and will start over.

Comment: Good job. This approach also has the benefit that you can switch between Node/npm versions at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that globally installing packages with `npm` links them into directories under `/usr/local/`, which are typically owned by the root user.

[Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is one way to circumvent such tricky permissions issues. It allows globally installed packages to be linked into directories in your home folder under `~/.nvm/versions/node/<version>`

Using my package manager, I removed `node` and related software such as `npm`.

I used `find /usr/local/ -name 'node_modules'` to scour `/usr/local/` for any vestiges of the packages I had previously installed globally with `npm`. Delete them all.

Then I installed `nvm` using the latest install script from https://github.com/creationix/nvm

In my case it was

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

I had to then link `nvm` into my environment path.
In my case, this meant manually editing my `.bashrc` profile to include this:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/zack/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

From there, I was ready to get the most recent LTS version of node through nvm

```
nvm install --lts
```

Now globally installed packages can be installed without `sudo` because they are deposited under `~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.2/` and everything works perfectly!